# How to compare two double number and find smaler

Tags: java, compare, double, rectangles

This class contains list of Rectangles and I need to find rectangle with smallest area.

I've found that need to compare rectangles by area, but it has the double precision.
I understand that my comparison remember the last one, but how we can do this checking here?

**Code:**

```
   /**
    * Gets the Rectangle with the smallest area
    * @return the rectangle with the smallest area or null if
    * there are no rectangles
    */
   public Rectangle smallestArea()
   {        
       if (list.size() == 0) return null;

       Rectangle smallest = list.get(0);           
       double smallestArea = smallest.getWidth() * smallest.getHeight();

       for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
           Rectangle next = list.get(i);
           double nextArea = next.getWidth() * next.getHeight();

           if ((nextArea - smallestArea) < 0) smallest = next;             
       }

       return smallest;
   }
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: why don't you try simple comparative ooperators?

Comment: @rptwsthi this didn't work correctly

Comment: How about implementing comparable in your rectangle class ?

Comment: @nazar_art You have also to keep saved/updated the smallestArea you have found because as written as it is, you are just comparing all rectangle areas to the 1st rectangle area in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update `smallestArea` local variable as well (one line more in your code):

```
   public Rectangle smallestArea()
   {        
       if (list.size() == 0) return null;

       Rectangle smallest = list.get(0);           
       double smallestArea = smallest.getWidth() * smallest.getHeight();

       for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
           Rectangle next = list.get(i);
           double nextArea = next.getWidth() * next.getHeight();

           if ((nextArea - smallestArea) < 0) { 
             smallest = next;         // <- Whenever you've updated smallest           
             smallestArea = nextArea; // <- Do not forget updating the smallestArea as well
           }  
       }

       return smallest;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm does not work because you need to update `smallestArea` as well:

```
if ((nextArea - smallestArea) < 0) {
    smallest = next; 
    smallestArea = nextArea; // <<== Here
}
```

Note that `(nextArea - smallestArea) < 0` is another way of saying `nextArea < smallestArea`, so this looks cleaner:

```
if (nextArea < smallestArea) {
    smallest = next; 
    smallestArea = nextArea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
double smallest = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;

// in the loop.
if (smallest > next)
    smallest = next;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides remembering what the smalles rectangle is, you also need to remember what the size of it is. Change the `if` inside the loop:

```
if (nextArea < smallestArea) {
    smallest = next;
    smallestArea = nextArea
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Rectangle smallestArea()
{        
   if (list.size() == 0) return null;

   Rectangle smallest = list.get(0);           
   double smallestArea = smallest.getWidth() * smallest.getHeight();

   for (int i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
       Rectangle next = list.get(i);
       double nextArea = next.getWidth() * next.getHeight();

       if ((nextArea - smallestArea) < 0){
          smallest = next;             
          smallestArea = nextArea;
       }
   }

   return smallest;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this? I think you can try this way

```
    List<Rectangle> list=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double> areaList=new ArrayList<>();
    for(Rectangle r:list){
        areaList.add(r.getHeight()*r.getHeight());
    }
    Collections.sort(areaList);
    System.out.println("Smallest "+areaList.get(0));
```

Answer (score -1):

Try,

```
int retval = Double.compare(nextArea, smallestArea);

if(retval < 0)
{
  System.out.println("smallestArea is greater than nextArea");
  smallest = next;
}
```

Comment: Using `Double.compare` simply because you want to check which of two `double` values is smaller is unnecessarily complicated. Just use `<` to compare them. Besides, this is not the problem in nazar_art's code.